# Getting available CSS values via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to build a HTML dashboard that fetches available css options for a given property.

For example [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) can have possible values of `row, row-reverse, column, column-reverse` etc.

Is there such a way to fetch those values via JS, so I can dynamically populate a drop down?

Such as;

`getCssPropertyValues("flex-direction"); // returns array.`